# Converting markdown to next.js page does not work properly

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I use the npm markdown-it to convert my markdown files into blog articles, but when I enter # abc in markdown, <h2>abc<h2>

I use the npm markdown-it to convert my markdown files into blog articles, but when I enter # abc in markdown, \<h2\>abc\<h2\>[description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbFKG.jpg) will appear in the blog article as text instead of magnifying the title. How can I solve the problem? This is my code:[https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ssangyongsport/nextjs-newhome/main/pages/blog/%5Bslug%5D.js?token=GHSAT0AAAAAACAXT26DH5RP7PSAEF5HGNMEZBW2UTQ%5C\](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ssangyongsport/nextjs-newhome/main/pages/blog/%5Bslug%5D.js?token=GHSAT0AAAAAACAXT26DH5RP7PSAEF5HGNMEZBW2UTQ%5C%5C)

Comment: The github link doesn't work, but are you setting the content into a div with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Comment: Hello,@rguarascia.ts this is my code: https://github.com/ssangyongsport/nextjs-newhome/blob/main/pages/blog/%5Bslug%5D.js